# UIVisualEffectView 'disappears' when placed against a white background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uivisualeffectview

I'm trying to recreate a UIVisualEffectView similar to the one used in the footer of App Store stories. While it looks pretty straight forward, I'm having trouble configuring the blur to respond the same way when against a white background.

Out of the box, UIVisualEffectView with a `.light`, `.extraLight`, `.prominent`, or `.default` blurEffect becomes pretty much invisible when placed above a white background. I think I'm missing something obvious with the vibrancy, but I've been tweaking values for a while now and I haven't been able to recreate the effect properly.

[image: Get app footer]

---

Here's what I'm doing, and what it looks like when against a completely white background.

```
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 300))
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
view.addSubview(backgroundView)

let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight))
blurView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 150)
backgroundView.addSubview(blurView)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the tone of your `UIVisualEffectView` by changing its background color. I guess you're looking for something like that

```
blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

Comment: I tried that! It's definitely closer to what they're doing in the App Store but it's not quite the same. The differences can be seen when the visual effect view is above colored content.

Comment: @elfanek I agree, but how do you measure the difference? For me blurView with `UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.7)` looks almost the same even in front of colored content. https://imgur.com/qvUALYD

Comment: It's easiest to see the differences when scrolling through a variety content. When adding a background color the blur muddies a bit. It's subtle lol but whatever Apple is doing is definitely cleaner. I'm convinced it's related to the vibrancy but I can't find the right configuration